# Trying to build GDAL from github using Visual Studio 2019 on windows 64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, gdal, proj

I want to use GDAL for a project that I am working on which is written in C++ using Visual Studio 16 2019. I am getting errors and I am finding difficulties in building the library. The steps I followed are following:
I have downloaded the source code from https://github.com/OSGeo/GDAL, unzipped it and opened using VS2019.
It shows the following errors:

```
-- Could NOT find ODBCCPP (missing: ODBCCPP_LIBRARY ODBCCPP_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find MSSQL_NCLI (missing: MSSQL_NCLI_LIBRARY MSSQL_NCLI_INCLUDE_DIR MSSQL_NCLI_VERSION)
-- Could NOT find MySQL (missing: MYSQL_LIBRARY MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Iconv (missing: Iconv_LIBRARY Iconv_CHARSET_LIBRARY Iconv_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_DIR)
-- Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_LIBRARY EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Failed to find XercesC (missing: XercesC_LIBRARY XercesC_INCLUDE_DIR XercesC_VERSION)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Deflate (missing: Deflate_LIBRARY Deflate_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR SSL Crypto)
-- Could NOT find CryptoPP (missing: CRYPTOPP_LIBRARY CRYPTOPP_TEST_KNOWNBUG CRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find PROJ (missing: PROJ_LIBRARY PROJ_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is
  at least version "6.0")
```

I could not figure out how I can include the directories to the PROJ and SWIG libraries and could not solve the other issues.

I tried to build the project using CMake, which gave the same error.

Comment: What part of [the instructions](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/BUILDING.md) is giving you trouble? Note that when you get to the documentation on the web site that you might have to install some dependencies first.

Comment: Where do you have PROJ installed? The [GDAL requirements page](https://gdal.org/development/dev_environment.html) says you need >= 6.0 installed.

Comment: Same issue here. I wonder, if they test building of GDAL on windows, or they write just theoretical steps in the documentation.